# Enumerate load-time woven aspects?

Tags: java, aspectj

Using AspectJ, I can get hold of the singleton instance of an aspect using the [`aspectOf()`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.6.10/aspectjrt-1.6.10-javadoc.jar!/org/aspectj/lang/Aspects.html#aspectOf%28java.lang.Class%29) method:

```
MyAspect aspect = Aspects.aspectOf(MyAspect.class);

// now perform post-application startup initialisation, eg:
aspect.setLogService(logging);
```

Is there a way to get a list of *all* of the aspects in my running Java application? I'm using AspectJ 1.6.7 with load-time weaving, but can upgrade versions if required.

A list of all of the aspects in my application will allow me to inject dependencies into them at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather hackish solution, but a solution nonetheless: manually load the `aop.xml` file from the classpath and parse it to get the aspect classnames:

```
final Enumeration<URL> urls =
  getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/aop.xml");

final Collection<String> aspectNames = new ArrayList<String>();

for (final URL url : urls) 
{
    final Stream xml = url.openStream();

    final DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = 
      DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    docBuilderFactory.setValidating(false);
    docBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);

    final XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    final Document aspectXml = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(xml);
    final XPathExpression selector = xpath.compile("//aspect/@name");

    final NodeList matches = 
      (NodeList) selector.evaluate(aspectXml, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    for (int i = 0; i < matches.getLength(); i++) 
    {
        aspectNames.add(matches.item(i).getNodeValue());
    }    
}
```

Then aspect instances can be fetched like so:

```
for (final String className : aspectNames) 
{
    final Class<?> aspectClass = Class.forName(className);
    final Object aspect = Aspects.aspectOf(aspectClass);

    // finally (!) do the initialisation on the aspect itself:
    aspect.setLogService(logging);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to list each and every one of your aspects, then maybe you should consider using another aspect to inject your dependencies?

If not, your DI framework may provide some useful mechanism.